# "What's the problem with you?" vs. "What's the matter with you?"

Tags: phrases, differences

Is there a difference between saying *What's the problem with you?* and *What's the matter with you?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As always, the answer depends on the context. In some cases, they may be interchangeable, but there's at least one instance in which they are not. *What's the problem with you?* is invariably critical, but *What's the matter with you?* may be used as a neutral inquiry about someone's medical condition.

Comment: Yes, because "what's the problem with you" presupposes that there is a problem with you, i.e. something about you needs fixing. "What's the matter with you" doesn't necessarily have that implication.

Answer (score 0):

I don't hear regular English speakers say "What's the problem with you?"  It's "What's wrong?", "What's the problem?", "What's the matter?" none of which are necessarily critical.  You can add "with you" to the first and last, which could sound critical, depending on the context, but saying "What's the problem with you?" doesn't sound like regular English to me.

Answer (score 0):

What's the problem with you is not a common expression. "What's the matter with you?" is commonly used, but the context and tone are  important, because it is used at least as often, if not more often, as a rhetorical statement of disapproval, even if the timber goes up at the end like a question. A native speaker of English who is very upset with someone (think road rage incident or nearly getting hit by a car) could also exclaim "what's your problem?" as an expression of anger or disbelief at another person's (usually reckless) conduct.

If you are genuinely concerned about someone's well-being, it is both safer and more natural to simply ask them "what is the matter?" or "what seems to be the problem?" These wordings put a sympathetic distance between a person and their problems.